# SQL Recursion statement for listing categories

Tags: mysql, sql, recursion, hierarchical-data

I have a categories table in my database with the following structure:

```
id | parent_id | name
```

Top level categories have a `parent_id` of 0, where as all other categories can be children of other categories. There are parents of categories, grand-parents, great-grandparents, etc.

This is my current SQL statement:

```
SELECT * from `categories` ORDER BY `parent_id`;
```

I want to see something like the following in my select box:

```
MOVIES
MOVIES -> ACTION
MOVIES -> ACTION -> ENGLISH
```

Is there an SQL statement that can handle this recursion in the categories?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree)

Comment: If you want to display all categories, just get all and associate with their parent.
If you want to get the hierarchy, you should do a query recursively if parent != 0 ...

Comment: no, you cannot do this in SQL. I'm reluctant to post this as an answer though. People don't like to hear the truth if its negative. you have to first fetch all the data and then build a proper recursive data structure from it.

Comment: Have a look at [**this**](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)